# sleep() does not work as I expected

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, sleep, uicolor

I'm having some trouble with sleep(). I have 10 UIButtons which are connected to the same IBAction called "buttons:". Now, the IBAction method should make all the buttons unenabled and turn the background color of them to red and then call a method called "nextButtonToEnable" which first has a sleep(1) and then a random int thats used by a switch which turns 1 of the buttons enabled and blue instead of red. Now to the problem, I want all the buttons to turn red when pressed and then after 1 sec delay another button will become blue, but that doesn't happen, what really happens is that when i press the blue button it stays blue during the whole delay of 1 sec and then it turns red and another button is turns blue.

here is my code

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIButton *b1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b2;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b3;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b4;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b5;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b6;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b7;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b8;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b9;
    IBOutlet UIButton *b10;
}
-(void)nextButtonToEnable;


@end
```

.m:

```
-(IBAction)buttons:(id)sender {
b1.enabled = NO;
b2.enabled = NO;
b3.enabled = NO;
b4.enabled = NO;
b5.enabled = NO;
b6.enabled = NO;
b7.enabled = NO;
b8.enabled = NO;
b9.enabled = NO;
b10.enabled = NO;
b1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b3.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b4.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b5.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b6.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b7.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b8.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b9.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
b10.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self nextButtonToEnable];
}

-(void)nextButtonToEnable {

sleep(1);

int nextButton = rand() % 10;

switch (nextButton) {
    case 0:
        b1.enabled = YES;
        b1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;
    case 1:
        b2.enabled = YES;
        b2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;
    case 2:
        b3.enabled = YES;
        b3.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;
    case 3:
        b4.enabled = YES;
        b4.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;
    case 4:
        b5.enabled = YES;
        b5.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;
    case 5:
        b6.enabled = YES;
        b6.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;
    case 6:
        b7.enabled = YES;
        b7.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;
    case 7:
        b8.enabled = YES;
        b8.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;
    case 8:
        b9.enabled = YES;
        b9.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;
    case 9:
        b10.enabled = YES;
        b10.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
}
```

So its like the sleep is between b1.enabled = NO; and b1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];.

How do i fix this because i haven't found anything on the internet. Mostly because I dont have a single clue what to search for :P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and not `sleep()`

Comment: Thank you, i typed [self performSelector:@selector(nextButtonToEnable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]; in the IBAction and it worked :D

Answer (score 0):

`sleep()` is deprecated, use `Sleep()` instead (capital S)

If you want to put your process to sleep for 1 second, you need to do:

```
Sleep(1000);
```

where 1000 is milliseconds

Comment: I have read about the Sleep and it gives you a warning "Semantic Issue: Implicit declaration of function 'Sleep' is invalid in C99"

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

That'll fix your problem.

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please include how/why your post will solve the problem.